# When would be best time to update an object in Ajax?

Tags: ajax

Im sending and receiving posts with ajax and php, now when would be the best time to update my response to my html, after send post or before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

The most common approach I have used/seen is to update your HTML after you receive a response from the PHP script you are executing via AJAX.

jQuery example:

```
$.post('script.php', {name_1: value_1, name_2: value_2}, function(data){
  /*
    this is the function that is fired upon a successful AJAX execution
    the data variable contains the data script.php outputs
  */
  //update html here
});
```